# Firebase value event listener firing even after activity is finished?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working with firebase and i noticed something strange.
One of the value event listener that i had registered in activity is fired even after i have finished the activity. 
I have added code to open a new activity in the'onDataChanged' method , so even if i am in a different activity the new activity is opened.  This is causing  big problems in the app.
I know that i have to call remove listener but i expected that the listener will be removed automatically after the activity is finished. Is there a simpler way in which i can remove all the value event listeners of an activity ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firebase Database listeners are not context bound. You will need to remove them explicitly in your code in the correct activity lifecycle event, as in Alex' answer.

Comment: Is there any way to attach it to a context ? I don't want to manually do it since there are a lot of listeners in each activity.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: As I said Firebase Database listeners are not context bound. You will have to track them in your code and detach them as Alex shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the listener once you leave the main activity. In order to do that, you can create a method like this:

```
private HashMap<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
public static void removeValueEventListener(HashMap<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> hashMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = entry.getKey();
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = entry.getValue();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }
}
```

Every time you want to remove a lister, you can use this line of code:

```
hashMap.put(yourRef, eventListener);
```

Than just call `removeValueEventListener(hashMap);` according to the activity life-cycle. You can add this line in your `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods. In this way **you can remove all the listeners at once**.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer , but i knew about this already . I want to know if there is any other way to remove all the listeners at the same time? Because manually doing it is going to take a long time.

Comment: Yes, actually there is. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is slightly other way

```
    mReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         //Your initial code:
         .....
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            mReference.removeEventListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mReference.removeEventListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            mReference.removeEventListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mReference.removeEventListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Not saying that this is the best way, but it helped me solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

For those who are starting in Android Studio like me and did not understand right away [Alex Mamo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44435838/4300670)'s answer, here comes a short example:

First declare your Firebase and HashMap variables like below.

```
private DatabaseReference NotifyGroupRef;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
private HashMap<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> groupCreatorAndKeys = new HashMap<>();
```

After, assign your Firebase Reference in **onCreate** like below.

```
NotifyGroupRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("NotifyGroup");
```

Create a function to add your listener like below.

```
private void updateNotifyGroupInternet(String groupCreator, String groupKey) {

    NotifyGroupRef.child(groupCreator).child(groupKey).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            String[] splittedSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().split("=");
            String clientId = splittedSnapshot[0].replace("{","");
            String notification = splittedSnapshot[1].replace("}", "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    groupCreatorAndKeys.put(NotifyGroupRef.child(groupCreator).child(groupKey), valueEventListener);

}
```

Stop listening when launching a new activity like below.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> entry : groupCreatorAndKeys.entrySet()) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = entry.getKey();
        ValueEventListener value = entry.getValue();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(value);
    }


}
```

And finally, add the listener again when returning to the activity by pressing the backbutton, for example:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> entry : groupCreatorAndKeys.entrySet()) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = entry.getKey();
        ValueEventListener value = entry.getValue();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(value);
    }

}
```

In my example, I've used different paths via variables `groupCreator` and `groupKey` and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

First declare your DatabaseReference and ValueEventListener

```
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
private final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

after that you can remove that listener in OnDestroy() or according to your activity life cycle

```
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(valueEventListener!=null)
    {
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }
}
```